# Spring Webflow model validation.

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

We have developed an internet bank project in our company. We have used spring-mvc in this project and all of property validations have been carried out using Hibernate validator. However for some of our services that have a state-machine nature, we need to use spring-webflow.

In doing so we need to validate models in spring webflow without adding any extra validators.  As you know There are 2 ways to validate a model programmatically:

1. Define validation logic in the model object.
2. Define a separate object called Validator to validate the model.

However, we DO NOT want to use none of these validation techniques.

For example lets imagine we had a Class named Customer. We used annotation validation for the properties in this class in our project. Now, we want to use this class as a model in view states in our webflow.

I was wondering if someone could help us how to validate models in spring webflow using annotation validation with hibernate validator.

Comment: Did you check this: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-jsr303-valid-example/

Comment: Yes I am one the followers of mkyong page. As I said before We want to use Spring-webflow. this example in mkyong page is for spring-mvc validation not for spring-webflow

Answer (score 0):

Spring Webflow 2.4 supports [JSR-303 validation and partial validation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.4.x/reference/htmlsingle/#view-validate) through the use of validation groups.

You need to add the following to the application context xml file:

```
<webflow:flow-registry flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices" />

<webflow:flow-builder-services id="flowBuilderServices" validator="validator" />

<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />
```

This will allow you to validate your model objects using annotations.